# Is there a way run multiple instance on jmeter-server on single machine

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have limited number of machines (3 machines). I want to simulate 5000 concurrent users for my website. I want to know if I can run multiple instance on jmeter-server on one host. something like this

host1:
192.168.1.1:3000
192.168.1.1:3001
192.168.1.1:3002

host2:
192.168.1.2:3000
192.168.1.2:3001
192.168.1.2:3002

I dont want to run independent jmeter instances.

Comment: how about installing VMs on your machine and mocking as they are executing from different machines, or you can try to use blazemeter

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found multiple remotes on one machine to be any better than a single jmeter on the machine.

I have even found the opposite, since there are a lot more overheads.

I have found on some tests that one jmeter master can generate more samples than two or more slaves running in distributed mode.

To do more samples, you need to be using less local resources for other stuff.  VMs, jmeter-server, etc all add overheads, unless you are running on a high power server that a single JVM can't make the most of.  Even then, the least overhead method is run another jmeter jvm.